# Adaptive Gridview depending on content

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Wanting an adaptive gridview to change depending on how much content is given to the gridview item. can only really get this to work with one column by setting vertical content alignment to stretch, but i would like to have more than one column. Below is a an example of what I'm needing help with example of problem:

[image: example of problem]

and what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: This article: [Windows 8 Beauty Tip: Using a VariableSizedWrapGrid in a GridView makes Grids Prettier](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at the VariableSizedWrapGrid, you can indicate for each item how much row or columnspan you want.

A good example and detail on how to use it is available here http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/windows-10-grouped-variablesizedwrapgrid-similar-to-windows-8